# Node.js application exiting whilst waiting for readdir callback

Tags: node.js, rxjs

I am writing a little library that will expand a given path and give a list of all folders and directories beneath it.

The function that reads the folder content looks like this:

```
function loadFolderContents(folder: string): Rx.Observable<string[]>{
    console.log(`loading path content: ${folder}`)
    const readDirObservable = Rx.Observable.fromNodeCallback<string[]>( fs.readdir )

    return readDirObservable(folder)
        .catch(() => Rx.Observable.empty())
        .do(folderContents => console.log(`loading path content: ${folder} COMPLETE - ${folderContents}`))
        .map(folderContents => folderContents.map( filepath => path.join(folder, filepath)));
}
```

somehow my application exits whilst waiting for this callback...

As an example I am trying to scan my C: drive. The content of the C drive is correctly loaded with maybe 20 sub folders loaded. It then loads around 3 sub folders and tried to load a 4th and then just dies. No error or log or anything.

I don't want to fix this by setting random timeouts, I want to understand why the programme is exiting like this.

The full code is [here](https://github.com/Roaders/rx-path-expander/blob/ad5d9c7b923747808a8f8d9d31c54ca2e7b7d6e4/src/lib/rx-path-expander.ts).

Thanks

Comment: does .catch(() => Rx.Observable.empty()) get called when an error occurs ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out what this is and (not surprisingly) it's me getting it wrong.

If an error occurs it's caught by the catch statement but the way the rest of the code works the next path is not passed to this function until the current one completes.
As an Rx.Observable.empty() is returned the code that passes the next path in doesn't know that this one is complete.